# SearchView from String xml

Tags: android-recyclerview, searchview, string.xml

What is the full code for creating a searchview in recycler view using items from string.xml and not adding them directly in Main Activity.I have tried almost everything but nothing has worked so far. There is probably an issue with:
String[] items = getResources().getstringarray(R array.item_names)